# Does CAST(DateTime AS DATE) cause the entire table to be CAST before comparison?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cast

This is a very common need in the WHERE clause of our SQL statements:

```
 CAST(Something.CreationDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@firstDate AS DATE)
 AND CAST(@lastDate AS DATE)
```

All of the fields are of type DateTime that are cast to DATE. Does this cause a conversion to run across the entire table first and then comparisons happens or is this very similar to a scan on that table?

Comment: Just a question if you have a column called `CreationDate`, why are you not storing it as a date?

Comment: It's an old standard for our software that actually stores the creation DateTime.

Comment: perhaps you should try it and look at the query plan and see what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Whipped up a simple example on this using a handy calendar table.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-04-16 09:35:36.510'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2014-05-16 09:35:36.510'


select
    *
from Calendar
where CAST(BaseDate AS date) > CAST(@StartDate AS date)
    AND CAST(BaseDate AS date) > CAST(@StartDate AS date)
```

When we look at the query plan for this we can see it's doing a simple index seek and all is well.

[image: IndexSeek]

Comment: Great! shouldn't the last line of the example be `CAST(BaseDate as date)<cast(@EndDate as date)`

Answer (score 2):

I think that in 2012 version (or earlier) an optimizer improvement made this cast especially not to do a conversion.

But it's always safe to use open-closed ranges for this type of queries, instead of the [*evil* `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (see Aaron Bertrand's blog for more details). No conversions of the `CreationDate` will be needed for this condition and indexes will be available for use:

```
WHERE Something.CreationDate >= CAST(@firstDate AS DATE)
  AND Something.CreationDate < DATEADD( day, 1 CAST(@lastDate AS DATE))
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the mandatory @AaronBertrand Link.